How do I express the speedup of the merge sort algorithm when I parallelize the divide step?
I am trying to solve the following exercise:
Consider the following recursive mergesort algorithm (another classic divide and conquer algorithm). Mergesort was first described by John Von Neumann in 1945. The basic idea is to divide an unsorted list x of m elements into two sublists of about half the size of the original list. Repeat this operation on each sublist, and continue until we have lists of size 1 in length. Then starting with sublists of length 1, “merge” the two sublists into a single sorted list. The code is:
Mergesort(m)
    var list left, right, result
    if length(m) <= 1
        return m
    else
        var middle = length(m) / 2
        for each x in m up to middle
            add x to left
        for each x in m after middle
            add x to right
        left = Mergesort(left)
        right = Mergesort(right)
        result = Merge(left, right)
        return result

Merge(left, right)
    var list, result
    while length(left) > 0 and length(right) > 0
        if first(left) <= first(right)
            append first(left) to result
            left = rest(left)
        else
            append first(right) to result
            right = rest(right)

    if length(left) > 0
        append rest(left) to result
    if length(right) > 0
        append rest(right) to result
    return result

The questions are:

Assume that you have Y cores on a multi-core processor to run MergeSort. Assuming
that Y is much smaller than length(m), express the speedup factor you might expect
to obtain for values of Y and length(m). Plot these on a graph.
Next, assume that Y is equal to length(m). How would this affect your conclusions
your previous answer? If you were tasked with obtaining the best speedup factor
possible (i.e., strong scaling), explain how you might change this code to obtain it.

I tried using Amdahl's law for parallelization but I don't know how to get the portion of parallelizable code.

"I don't know how to get the portion of parallelizable code" If you split the merge sort in N steps, it is significantly simpler to solve the problem. For example, the final merge step is 100% sequential. The one just before can run on 2 cores but no more, etc. You can assume each step in sequential takes the same time T (though in practice it is certainly not true because of cache effects for example). The final parallel execution time is the sum of each (parallel) step. The speed up is ParallelTime/SequentialTime.

Note this also assume there is a barrier at the end of each step and the work is perfectly balanced but I think this is very reasonable assumptions for an academic exercice (and it makes things significantly simpler while not being too far from the real-world).

@JérômeRichard the final [each?] merge step is 100% sequential while I usually think in-place array sort, the question is presented with an implementation creating separate lists left and right. What if I start from both ends?

What would be the difference for Y much smaller than the length of the list and Y equal the length of the list?

And would the speed up for bigger lists be bigger or smaller than for smaller lists?

The question does not supply any information about instruction speed versus memory speed, or if each of the cores has it's own local cache (for X86, local L1 and L2 caches are common), or what each core's cache size is. Without code or data cache, and if all instruction and data accesses occur through a common memory bus, then memory operations can't be parallelized (just register operations assuming each core has its own set of registers). Actual performance gain can't be estimated without this information.
The easiest way to implement this is to split the array into Y sub-arrays, sort each of the Y sub-arrays, then use Y/2 cores to merge Y sorted sub-arrays into Y/2 sorted sub-arrays, Y/4 cores ... Y/4 sorted sub-arrays, and a final merge with a single core as commented by Jerome Richard.
The example code is inefficient, appending is a relatively slow operation, (unless these are linked lists), and indexing a pre-allocated array is much faster. It's not clear if the example code is to be modified for multi-threading, or if the multi-threading code can just call the example code to merge sort each of the Y sub-arrays as noted with my "easiest way" paragraph.

The exercise has the basic concept of the original von Neumann merge sort wrong. The original mergesort was a bottom up iterative merge sort. It could be considered divide and conquer, but the divide step "divides" an array of m elements into m sub-arrays of size 1, and just initializes working variable to start the merging process without any recursion (early computers didn't have a native stack).
In 1945, von Neumann described an algorithm to merge two sorted runs. The idea probably came from the 1937 IBM 077 collator, which could merge two sorted decks of cards. In 1948, Goldstine and von Neumann described
an algorithm for a complete bottom up merge sort.

Thanks for the response. I think the exercise is mainly focused on a more theoretical approach but it is true it seems to give very little data.
I specially don't understand what I am supposed to do with the statement "express the speedup factor you might expect to obtain for values of Y and length(m)" given the approach you suggest.
